# How to simplify and reduce noise from this shapefiles and get clean and proper buildings in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, footprint

[image]

The image being provided is very irregular and includes alot of noise.

How can I:

1. Remove irregular noise
2. Show regular buildings

Comment: You'll find it easier to filter/clean the raster rather than the vector. What else have you got? DSM/DEM/LiDAR? Do you have access to ERDAS or ENVI?

Comment: I have DSM file with with i used the command "Raster to vector". At the end the final output which I want is proper buildings and roads being identified. How should I proceed?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. Please always specify the exact version of software in use.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have enough information to achieve the result you are wanting. You could try slope on the DSM, all roads are mostly flat and buildings tend to have the same roof pitch, classify the slope to match your data, eliminate variant areas (focal statistics should help) and go from there.. your task is **very difficult** without properly classified LiDAR and DEM and I don't think you will get a very good result without more information. ENVI or ERDAS might be better than ArcGIS for this task, but you could try supervised classification in Esri and see if that works for you.

Comment: Can you help me out with a way for extracting buildings and roads with a fully or semi-automatic way? The files which I have include:

1.) TIFF
2.) Point cloud(LAS file)
3.) Drone imagery
4.) High quality aerial photos

Please help me out with a way using ArcGIS or any other software with some link or tutorial with which I can properly extract building footprint i.e. clean

Answer (score 2):

There are two tools that could help you :

- simplify to remove the extra vertices resulting from the raster to vector conversion. Bend simplify would be best but it takes longer.
- eliminate to remove the small inclusions in the building by merging with their neighbours. You must, therefore, select your inclusion first, e.g. based on a maximum size.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get back to your "Raster to vector" tool again, because output vector is too curved. Try it with "simplify polylines (optional)" unchecked.

Then you can use simplify tool.

Comment: The result when I have shown in the image above is a result of "Raster to vector". I am looking forward for a way by which I can clean it so that I can properly identify the building and roads